# Why row is not deleted in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

can you please tell me why my row is not deleted.I I make a demo in which I added the student name .I am able to add the student name .Now I have two issue I am not able to delete row and Edit.can you please tell where i am wrong ?

here is my demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/1lem6t4h7b6Eefsz32t6?p=preview

```
app.controller("studentcntr",['$scope',function(scope){
    scope.studentDetail=[];

    scope.addStudent=function(){
        bootbox.prompt("Enter Name!",function(res){
            console.log(res);
            if(res==null){

            }else {
                scope.studentDetail.push({ name: res });

            }

            scope.$digest();
        });


    };

    scope.editRowName=function (name) {
      // body...
     // alert(name);
     setTimeout(function() {
      $('.bootbox-input').val(name); 
     }, 10);

    }

     scope.deleteRow=function (id) {
      // body...
      alert('s'+id)
      $('#'+id).remove();
    }





}])
```

I am able to delete row .But problem is that when I remove row and add new name it create again  delete row why ? why it is now delete permanently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*why it is now delete permanently*

As you are not deleting it from `scope.studentDetail` it is persisting.

Changes

*HTML*

```
    <td ><button ng-click="editRowName(student)">Edit</button></td>
    <td ><button ng-click="deleteRow($index)" >Delete</button></td>
```

*Script*

```
scope.editRowName=function (student) {
  bootbox.prompt({
    title: "What is your name?", //Title
    value: student.name, //Pre-filled name
    callback: function(result) {
      student.name = result; //Update name
      scope.$digest();
    }
  });
}

scope.deleteRow=function ($index) {
  scope.studentDetail.splice($index, 1);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PnqRz9Pm04eDmnGfy9Bj?p=preview)

Comment: thanks satpal how I edit my name ...mean when I click edit it show same alert before adding with name.now user can edit name

Comment: mean when your press edit it show promt with name in text field ..and then user can edit the name ..and save it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were removing the element from DOM and not from the data model..

http://plnkr.co/edit/a4WLy1ckQHT68uz1CGeh?p=preview

It works for both edit and delete.

```
<td><button ng-click="editRowName($index, student.name)">Edit</button></td>
<td><button ng-click="deleteRow($index)" >Delete</button></td>
```

and in the controller

```
scope.editRowName=function (index, name) {
    scope.currentIndex = index;

   bootbox.prompt("Enter New name for " + name,function(res){
        console.log(res);

        if(res==null){

        }else {
          if (scope.currentIndex === -1) {
            scope.studentDetail.push({ name: res });
          } else {
            scope.studentDetail[scope.currentIndex].name = res;
            scope.currentIndex = -1;
          }

        }

        scope.$digest();
    });

}

 scope.deleteRow=function (id) {
  scope.studentDetail.splice(id, 1);
}
```